# In Leaflet.js, is there a way to iterate through all currently-existing markers?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to make it so my map icons scale in size with zoom, rather than being a static 38x38. If there is any way to do that with CSS, I'd be fine with that, too. I think that would also include being able to iterate through all markers, though, which I can't find a way to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just keep a reference of each of your markers? or put them in a Layer Group? I am still trying to figure out what is the use case for using _markers_ and trying to scale their icon with zoom?

Comment: See also http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-eachlayer

Answer (score 1):

The markers should all be available in the DOM, they have their own "pane" with the classname `leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane`. The markers them selves have at least the `leaflet-marker-icon` class.

You can use "standard" DOM queries to access them (e.g. querySelectorAll). You may want to check if there is a plugin available for your use case, leaflet has a rich ecosystem of plugins.

Comment: No offense, but I do not think that DOM manipulation should be necessary (or used) with Leaflet. Leaflet allows you do almost anything that you can think of. And, if it doesn't , it would be better to request that it does. I might do some DOM manipulation in a quick hack, but I would not allow it into production code (YkMMV).

Answer (score 1):

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You want to change the size of your markers with the zoom level, and you thought "I know! I'll iterate through the markers!", and you don't know how to do that, so you ask for a solution for the second problem.

Do, how does one change size of marker icons depending on zoom level?

There are several approaches.

One is to attach an event handler to the `zoomend` event of the map, and inside that event handler iterate through every marker. You can achieve that by calling [`map.eachLayer(...)`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-eachlayer), checking if the layer is a marker (`lyr instanceof L.Marker`), and reassigning its `L.Icon`.

Another approach is to attach an event handler to the zoomend event of the map *per marker*, kinda:

```
for (i in data) {
    ...
    var marker = L.marker(data[i].coords, ...);
    map.on('zoomend', function(){ 
        if (map.getZoom() > 15) {
            marker.setIcon(...);
        } else {
            marker.setIcon(...);
        }
    });
}
```

And another approach would be to use [`Leaflet.ZoomCSS`](https://github.com/dagjomar/Leaflet.ZoomCSS), which will change the map's CSS classes depending on its zoom level, allowing you to handle styling there.

Comment: I was interested in using the Leaflet.ZoomCSS, but it apparently leaves the old classes (see here: http://i.imgur.com/Gu6Q5bQ.png) whenever you change your zoom level, and that seems... I don't know, like a huge mess?